# Is there a way to activate the syntax highlighting in Confluence markdown code?

Tags: markdown, syntax-highlighting, confluence

The markdown in Confluence seems not to render syntax highlighting, as you can see below, as opposed to the code inserted via code block.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same experience. I do not think it is possible as Confluence does not have its own syntax highlighting engine and that that the code block (https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/code-block-macro-139390.html) is your best shot, as you mentioned yourself.